# "The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to int"

Tags: java, arrays

i tried to sort an array of integers using bubble sort, but when i try to compare index 0 with index 1, it pop up error message that says "The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to int". Below is my code.

```
package arraytest;

public class BubbleSort {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int [] bblSort = {30, 45, 8, 204, 165, 95, 28, 180, 110, 40};

    for(int i=0; i<bblSort.length; i++){
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}

public void sort(int bblSort){

   int temp=0;
   for(int i=0; i<bblSort-1; i++){
       for(int j=0; j<bblSort-1 -i; j++){
           if(bblSort[j] > bblSort[j+1]){
               temp = bblSort[j];
               bblSort[j] = bblSort[j + 1];
               bblSort[j+1] = temp;
           }
       }

   }
}
}
```

Comment: The [] are missing in method definition. It should be  public void sort(int [] bblSort) not public void sort(int bblSort)

Comment: When you post, please remember to include the *entire* error message.  In this case, the position (line and character) would get a faster response.  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
public static int[] sort(int bblSort[]){

    int temp=0;
    for(int i=0; i<bblSort.length-1; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<bblSort.length-1 -i; j++){
            if(bblSort[j] > bblSort[j+1]){
                temp = bblSort[j];
                bblSort[j] = bblSort[j + 1];
                bblSort[j+1] = temp;
            }
        }

    }
    return bblSort;
}
```

Comment: won't compile. what about `int[]`?

Comment: what do you mean? just tried it in Eclipse with java 1.8 and it compiled fine. Also, Im pretty sure from my basic java classes you could use `int[] name` or `int name[]` interchangeably

Comment: The body itself may complile, while `bblSort-1` should not anymore. Thus, the answer is incomplete and leads to another error. However, sorry about the confusion with `int[] a` vs  `int a[]`

Comment: yep, you are correct, provided a more complete answer, my bad